# A function which infinitely changes concavity but is everywhere non-decreasing

Tags: derivatives

For the infinitely changing concavity part, I have come up with this specific example $y = ^4\sin\frac{1}{x}$.

Derivative of $\sin\frac{1}{x}$  is  $-\frac{\cos\frac{1}{x}}{x^2}$, and $x^2$ will always be positive, however $\cos\frac{1}{x}$ is only positive in the first quadrant.

And for the everywhere non-decreasing part, I have not idea where to start.

How should I define the domain to fit the requirement? Please leave some hints!

Much appreciated!

Comment: Precisely what do you mean by _infinitely changes concavity_?

Comment: I'm sure he means the second derivative changes its sign infinitely many times.

Comment: You can find some examples in [Equation for a smooth staircase function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1671132/318073), such as $x+ \sin(x)$.

Comment: Assuming you mean a function with ["infinitely many flex points"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/71436/318073).

Comment: I see. What about the everywhere non-decreasing requirement? I am not sure what does that means.

Comment: Everywhere non-decreasing means there are no values $a,b$ such that $a \lt b$ and $f(a) \gt f(b)$.  It means it goes flat or upwards at all points.

Comment: You can show that $y=f(x)$ is increasing (non-decreasing) on $(a,b)$ by showing that the derivative is nonnegative, i.e. $f’\left( x \right) \ge 0\;\forall\;x \in \left( {a,b} \right).$